# What do "soundness" and "completeness" mean?

Tags: logic, terminology, computer-science, rewriting-systems

Soundness and completeness seem to occur in multiple scenarions:

1. [In mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Relation_to_completeness) they are used to describe the
   relationship between syntax and semantics of logic systems.
2. In [relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms),

   > The Armstrong's axioms are **sound** in generating only functional dependencies in the closure of a set of functional dependencies
   > (denoted as $F^{+}$) when applied to that set (denoted as $ F$).
   > They are also **complete** in that repeated application of these
   > rules will generate all functional dependencies in the closure
   > $F^+$.
3. In Baader's  *Term rewriting and all that*, ["soundness"](https://books.google.com/books?id=i37uBgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT24&dq=Term%20rewriting%20and%20all%20that%3A%20Definition%202.1.3&pg=PT27#v=onepage&q=soundness&f=false) and
   ["completeness"](https://books.google.com/books?id=i37uBgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT24&dq=Term%20rewriting%20and%20all%20that%3A%20Definition%202.1.3&pg=PT27#v=snippet&q=completeness&f=false) appear multiple times, for example

   > The popularity of measure functions into N is in part explained by the following **completeness** result:
   >
   > Lemma 2.3.3 A finitely branching reduction terminates iff there is a monotone embedding into (N, >).
   >
   > Proof The "if" direction follows from the **soundness** of the measure function approach. For the other direction, let —> be a
   > terminating and finitely branching reduction.

I guess there are other examples of using the two words.

What do "soundness" and "completeness" mean?

Do they have different meanings outside mathematical logic?

Do they necessarily mean the two opposite directions of a "if and only if" proposition?
If yes, which direction is soundness and which is completeness?

Where do they come from? (Not mathematical logic, since they may have different meanings outside it?)

Thanks.

Comment: Purely from their linguistic meaning: sound = healthy, not sick (used as such in "being of sound mind" etc), cognate to German gesund, Dutch gezond, West Frisian sûn etc. So a system being sound means that "nothing bad comes from it", that "all is well inside". Complete of course means that you have everything you could have (within a context), like your collection of base ball cards can be complete, it's not missing anything. So soundness is "internal" , completeness is in relation to a whole, so "external".

Comment: Check out the first chapter of Richard Kaye's book on Mathematical Logic. He gives a beautiful intuition using Konig's Lemma.

Comment: Basically:- **Sound:** Anything we might get is something we would want.  **Complete:** Anything we might want is something we could get.

Answer (score 5):

As Henno Brandsma  commented, soundness is a measure of health of the system (does it do anything we would not want it to?), and completeness is a measure of usefullness (could it do anything we may want it to?).

Basically:

- **Sound:** Anything we might get is something we would want.  *Nothing bad can happen*.
- **Complete:** Anything we might want is something we could get. *Anything good may happen*.

So a logic system's rules of syntax are *sound* when nothing they derive will have invalid semantics and *complete* when they may derive anything with valid semantics.

So, Armstrong's axiom are *sound* because they generate *only* elements of $F^+$ when applied to $F$, and *complete* because they *can* generate *all* elements of $F^+$ when applied to $F$.

Comment: So they are the two directions of the equivalence "good if and only if happens".  Soundness is the "if" and completeness is the "only if".

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess, which happens to be somehow similar to some replies and comments, or my misunderstanding.

Completeness and soundness apply (only?) to propositions that look like that given a set $T$ and another set $S$,  $S=T$.

$T$ is usually a target, and $S$ is usually the result of a construction with a goal of  matching $T$.
In that sense, $S \subseteq T$ is soundness, and $S\supseteq T$ is completeness.